# How can a client use prestored server's certificate to do SSL handshake?

Tags: c, openssl, ssl-certificate, handshake

I know that during normal SSL handshake, the client receives the server's certificate and verifies it, then uses the server's public key to encrypt the session key.

I want to write a SSL client in C language on Linux. During SSL handshake, it doesn't have to wait for the server's certificate and it sends the session key encrypted with the server's public key that have already been downloaded previously.

I am learning how to use OpenSSL, I only need the do-handshake part here.

Thanks for attention. Why to do this? The ISP or gateway can censor the certificate and block the connection according to names in the certificate.

Comment: why? How to you tell the server not to send the certificate? how do you handle a changed certificate? Sounds like a bad idea to me, could this be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: In order to do this, you would need access to both client and server code, and once implemented, this handshake would only work between your client and your server, i.e. the server could not communicate with any other clients.

Comment: "*How can a client use prestored server's certificate to do SSL handshake?*" Just use it, ignoring what the server sent to the client?

Comment: *"...then uses the server's public key to encrypt the session key"* - Not for much longer. RSA Key Transport is removed in TLS 1.3. The only thing available will be Key Agreement schemes, like ephemeral Diffie-Hellman. Most well-configure TLS 1.0-TLS 1.2 servers only offer ephemeral Diffie-Hellman nowadays.

Comment: *"...I want to write a SSL client in C language on Linux"* - See the sample code for [TLS Client](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/SSL/TLS_Client) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Comment: *"... prestored server's certificate to do ..."* - This sounds like you want to perform certificate pinning. Also see [Certificate and Public Key Pinning](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning) on the OWASP website. It includes an OpenSSL example.

Comment: Perhaps you want PGP? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Good_Privacy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is impossible. As part of the SSL (or TLS) protocol, the server will always send its certificate.

If you would like to bypass ISP censorship, I recommend using a VPN or Tor.

Comment: Unless both peers support, and agree on, one of the 'anonymous' or PSK or SRP keyexchanges -- but no public server does that; you'd have to run your own server, and if you do that you could more easily (and less noticeably) use normal certificate-based keyexchange with a name you've chosen to be innocuous.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Can the client pretend it receive the certificate (use a prestored certificate) and fulfill the handshake anyway?

Comment: @judian: not likely. If the ISP or other MitM spliced the cert message out of TCP but left everything else including adjusted sequence numbering, and you could fake the cert message (not just the single cert) _perfectly_ bit for bit, in principle the handshake could continue. Note it must be only the cert message not the full flight; you still need serverhello and often serverkx. But in reality the MitM will block the connection entirely, unless you get the server to not send the cert(s) at all, and that will happen only with a server you run (or have a friend run). _And_ you disable SNI.

Comment: *As part of the SSL (or TLS) protocol, the server will always send its certificate."* - When using anonymous protocols, like Anonymous Diffie-Hellman (ADH), the server does *not* send its certificate. Unfortunately they are still part of the standard.